# How could I use per-folder color schemes? (Sublime Text 3)

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, color-scheme

Here is my problem: when writing javascript for both server and client-side, I regularly share methods and/or have close file names. I would love to be able to keep the context in mind, just by the background color of the opened files. I thus look for a way to tell sublime text to use one color scheme for files in the server folder and an other for those in the client folder: any clue on how I could do that?

I'm not sure it's even possible as it would imply a per-folder config file I guess, but that's my bottle in the sea...
thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with [projects](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html). Set up a project for your client-side folder, and another for your server-side folder. Then, go to **`Project -> Edit Project`** and you'll see something like this:

```json
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "/home/mattdmo/Projects/js/MySweetApp/server-side"
        }
    ]
}
```

There are two other top-level arrays you can add: `"settings"` and `"build_systems"`. The `settings` section can include anything that goes in **`Preferences -> Settings-User`**, including `"color_scheme"`:

```json
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "/home/mattdmo/Projects/js/MySweetApp/server-side"
        }
    ],

    "settings":
    {
        "color_scheme": "Packages/Neon Color Scheme/Neon.tmTheme"
    }
}
```

Just edit both `.sublime-project` files you made earlier to add a `settings` section and different `color_scheme` choices within, and you'll be all set.

---

### EDIT

While pondering this again, I came up with a different solution using a plugin. Create a new Python file with the following contents:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ClientServerColorSchemeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):
        if "/server/" in self.view.file_name():
            self.view.settings().set("color_scheme", 
                "Packages/User/server.tmTheme")
        elif "/client/" in self.view.file_name():
            self.view.settings().set("color_scheme", 
                "Packages/User/client.tmTheme")


class ClientServerEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    def on_load_async(self, view):
        view.run_command("client_server_color_scheme")
```

Make sure you adjust the `"color_scheme"` settings to the color schemes you want to use for client and server files, and feel free to tweak `"/server/"` and/or `"/client/"` in the `if/elif` statements if you want to make them more specific. If you're on Windows, change the forward slashes `/` to double back-slashes `\\`. Save the file as `Packages/User/client_server_color_scheme.py` where `Packages` is the folder opened when selecting the **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** menu option.

Once saved, the event listener will start up immediately, and any file you open that contains the specified path will have the color scheme set to whatever you indicate. All other files from other paths will use your default color scheme.

Please note that this plugin will only work in ST3. To make it work in ST2, change `def on_load_async` to `def on_load`.

Comment: thank you for the answer but as I understand it, it doesn't exactly solve my problem: this would allow me to have different color schemes for different projects but not different color schemes in a single project/workspace: I can't have the left pan in a color and the right in an other one...

Comment: that would need something like:

`{"folders":
[
{"path": "/path/to/server","settings": {"color_scheme": "one.tmTheme"}},
{ "path": "/path/to/server/client", "settings": {"color_scheme": "two.tmTheme"}}
]}`

Comment: @maxlath unfortunately, that's not possible, as you can't have `"settings"` under `"folders"`. Instead of having your client and server files open in two different panels, you can have them in two different windows, one with the server project and one with the client project. The only other alternative is to write a plugin that parses the path of the open file and sets the color scheme accordingly.

Comment: yes, that's what I was afraid of. I might try the two-windows solution but I'm afraid Alt-Tab'ing through my files is worse for contextualizing than the initial problem, with terminals and browser in the way. Plus other one-window functionalities such as the good old Ctrl+P file switcher... in any case, thanks for the per-project settings tip :)

Comment: @maxlath please see my edit above for a different solution that may fit your needs better.

Comment: The python is great. Boy this would make a great plugin... ;)

Comment: @DaveSanders maybe, but it would require configuration code and documentation in order to make it robust and easier to use, and based on the fact that it's only gotten 4 upvotes in the last two years, I don't know if there's a great demand for something like this. The optimal way of working with different folders is by using [projects](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects), and you can already specify project-specific color schemes, so I'm not sure what this plugin would add.

Comment: @DaveSanders Now that I think about it a little more, it may add something, as  the user's client and server code could be in the same Sublime project, but they may still wish for a way to distinguish between the two. Maybe I'll publish it, but I still don't think there's too much of an audience. I could be wrong, though. It's happened before....

Comment: @MattDMo This would make a great little plugin. Especially with a configurable word to watch for as well as configurable color scheme to apply. I have wanted exactly this for my files in "dist" for ages.

Comment: @atomless OK, the masses have spoken. I'll get to work on it.

Comment: Thanks for the code! A plugin would be great.
For me on Windows replacing the forward slashes with double slashes didn't work, I had an error "Error loading colour scheme... Unable to open...", but when I returned the forward slashes, it worked

Answer (score 3):

I modified MattDMo's solution and it works with the latest Sublime Text 3 (build 3143):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
class ColorSchemeByPathCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        settings = self.view.settings()
        if "/test/" in self.view.file_name():
            settings.set('color_scheme', "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Orange01 (SL).tmTheme")
        else:
            settings.set('color_scheme', "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Blue01 (SL).tmTheme")
class ColorSchemeByPathEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load_async(self, view):
        view.run_command("color_scheme_by_path")
```